# Load javascript into div when user scroll position reaches it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I want to make the script load into the div only when user reaches it. I am trying to accomplish this using jQuery, but no success. Maybe you can help. Here is the code:

```
var scrollFromTop = $("#float_div_id").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > scrollFromTop) {
        var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
        s.src = 'javascript code src which i want to append on scroll';
        document.getElementById('float_div_id').appendChild(s);
    }
});
```

Comment: Just a side question: why would you create a script element inside the DOM? is it so heavy that you can't include it first?

Comment: Basically the div is empty. I want to append the script which will load the content inside that div. I do not want to load that script until user reaches the div and when the user reaches it, i want to load the script inside that particular div.

Comment: Why don't you just implement a function that, when the user scrolls that div, load the content you need? I mean, I'm not getting why you would load a script instead of the content.

Comment: What is not working? Add a `console.log` to check if ever the `scrollTop()` value goes beyond the offset.

Comment: @briosheje Can you please give me a simple example of jsfiddle how to do that ?

Comment: @Pandemum I can't do a fiddle if I have no idea of what you have to include.. As far as you are including a script, you can just COPY the content of tha script, paste it inside a function and invoke it when you scroll on the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `$(this).scrollTop()` would be coming out to be lesser than `scrollFromTop`.

Change your if condition to this and try again :

```
if ($(this).scrollTop() + $(window).height()  > scrollFromTop)
```

Comment: The problem in my case is that console.log gives me message that i have scrolled to the particular point, but the content is not being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look at [waypoint library](https://github.com/imakewebthings/waypoints). It trigger an event when user scroll on a specific element and them you can execute some coding (tempting ?)

```
var waypoint = new Waypoint({
  element: document.getElementById('thing'),
  handler: function(direction) {
    alert('You have scrolled to a thing')
  }
})
```

Then after scrolling, you should use [$.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) with a separate JS file :

> Description: Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

```
$.getScript('/javascript/myscript.js');
```

And be careful about using asynchronous if some code require your new js file :

```
$.getScript('/javascript/myscript.js', function() {
    // do something here
});
```

let me know if this work for you :D

Comment: The problem in my case is that console.log gives me message that i have scrolled to the particular point, but the content is not being loaded.

Comment: Are you trying to put HTML or Javascript code in your 'float_div_id' ?

Comment: I am trying to load javascript

Comment: Since you seems to use jQuery, you should give a try with $.getScript() :D. I will update my answer including this solution !